# How can I solve the error occurred while importing Tensorflow package using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pip

I have installed the package of Tensorflow but when imported it throws this error:

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 15, in swig_import_helper
    import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 15, in swig_import_helper
    import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error
```

I tried upgrading the package using command:
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
but nothing changed,it stated requirements already satisfied....

Comment: Tensorflow is currently not compatible with Python 3.12.

Answer (score 0):

> import tensorflow Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py",
> line 66, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 28, in 
> _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"

It appears that you are using Python 3.12. Please note that Tensorflow currently do not support Python 3.12. Kindly try using a version between Python 3.8 and 3.11.

Follow the link below for instructions on installing TensorFlow on Windows:[Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)